# kv plugin: Check if value is an array, and assign value to new field

Tags: ruby, plugins, logstash, key-value

The Logstash key-value plugin generates an array if there are duplicate keys; else, just a value.

How can I use the Ruby code plugin to check which it is?

- If it is an array, use the first value.
- If it is a string literal, simply use that value.

Here I use the `kv` plugin to parse the DATE field out. That is working, and placed into kv.DATE. Where am I going wrong here?

```
    ruby {
        code => "
            if event.get("[kv][DATE]").kind_of(Array)
                add_field => { "mydate" => "%{[kv][DATE][0]}"}
            else
                add_field => { "mydate" => "%{[kv][DATE]}"}
        "
    }
```

Comment: Why you use `event.get("[kv][DATE]")`?

Comment: I am new to Ruby... what do you recommend?

Comment: Try this: ‘if [kv][DATE].kind_of(Array)’